# Using devise_invitable with enum User roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-activerecord, devise-invitable

**1. Description core problem**

I am implementing the `devices_invitable gem` for inviting users. The gem is correctly added, as I am able to send users the standard devices_invitable email to invite them for the application.

**The problem that I am encountering, is that I am not sure how to enable an admin (to be identified with enum) to assign the role of the user they are inviting (e.g. they should enter an email AND role of the user they invite, which should then be correctly added to my DB).**

**Note:** *As you can see below, I'm currently trying to solve it using nested forms with the cocoon gem, but I am open to other approaches.*

**2. My current application**

The application has 2 tables with a many to-many relationship between them:

(i) Users, with role attributes defined by enum.

(ii) Parks

The idea is to let an admin invite a new user to a park (not entire application) by entering email+role.

**3. The code**

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_parks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :parks, :through =>  :user_parks
  enum role: [:owner, :admin, :employee, :accountant]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :admin
  end

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :invitable
end
```

**park.rb**

```
class Park < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_parks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :user_parks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: ->(attrs) { attrs['email'].blank? || attrs['role'].blank?}
end
```

**parks_controller.rb**

```
class ParksController < ApplicationController

def update
    @park = Park.find(params[:id])
    authorize @park
    url = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referrer)
    last_action = url[:action]
    if last_action == 'edit_users' & @park.user.last.nil?
      @user=@park.user.last.invite!(email: park_params[:user][:email])
    end
    @park = @park.update_attributes(park_params)
    redirect_to parks_path
  end

def edit_users
    @park = Park.find(params[:id])
    authorize @park
 end

 private
 def park_params
    params.require(:park).permit(:name, users_attributes: [:email, :role, :_destroy])
  end

end
```

**edit_users.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'users_edit_form', park: @park%>
```

**_users_edit_form**

```
<%= simple_form_for [@park] do |f|%>

<h1>Park</h1>
<% @park.users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.email %>
  <% end %>

<div> 
<% f.simple_fields_for User.new, :url=> new_user_invitation_path, html: { class: 'form-inline' } do |user| %>
  <%= user.input :email %>
  <%= user.input :role, priority: [:employee], collection:[:owner, :admin, :employee, :accountant] %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Invite User', class: 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>

</div> 
#TEST for standard view (sends invite but does not assign park/role)
<%# link_to "new user add", new_user_invitation_path %>


<%= f.button :submit, 'Invite User', class: 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

1st issue I can see is you are using a bitwise & on this line:

```
if last_action == 'edit_users' & @park.user.last.nil?
```

you would usually use a logical and `&&` or `and`

2nd issue with that line is `@park.user` should be `@park.users` if it's declared as a `has_many`

3rd issue is I'm not sure you need to be looking at `request.referrer`?

Assuming you can get to the invite! line then you might want to check the docs for the 2 different versions of invite!

When the user is already created:

```
user = User.find(42)
user.invite!(current_user)  # current user is optional to set the invited_by attribute
```

[see example in README](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#sending-an-invitation-after-user-creation)

OR

When the user isn't created yet:

```
User.invite!(email: 'new_user@example.com', name: 'John Doe')
# => an invitation email will be sent to new_user@example.com
```

[see example in README](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#send-an-invitation)